# Итератор end() в деревьях

Tags: алгоритм, дерево

Какая реализация итератора end() в деревьях наиболее простая и правильная(та, что находится за последним)?

P.S.
Не считая sentinel реализации.

Comment: А чем не нравится sentinel? Вообще итерация подразумевает определённый порядок обхода, но если взять "какой-то" порядок и предположить, что все обходимые узлы дерева хранятся в некотором линейном контейнере, то наиболее просто использовать end() и всё остальное именно этого контейнера.

Comment: @Lyth, Это не очень разумно, т.к. затрачивает на копирование время. Также, во время работы могут быть insert/erase, тогда придеться менять и сам контейнер. При большом количестве элементов это станет сильно заметным. В общем, не придумал ничего лучше(как минимум потому, что это константная память и O(logn) по времени), чем просто поддерживать его отдельно(помимо sentinel реализации).

Comment: А как может реализация быть более или менее правильной? Мне всегда казалось, что правильность — это булева величина: либо правильно, либо неправильно.